# Outlook add-in in contacts page

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am currently developing an outlook add-in and I want to have a button when I open the contacts page. I have checked the link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint

But these move the button on the email compose and email read pages. I was wondering how to use this to move the button to the contacts page.

Comment: Which extensionpoint are you using in the manifest? Outlook add-ins are supported in email/calendar surfaces as of now. Are you trying to use it for "Contacts" (or People) module?

Comment: Thanks you for your response. Yeah, I was hoping for a Contacts module. Is there any information on when this would be available ? or if it is indeed would be added in next updates

Comment: Currently the feature you requested is not available. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT the user voice page is unavailable

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT is there any update on the feature? nearly 2.5 years passed, so hopefully there is a way to handle the contacts?

Comment: We recommend you to upvote or create a new Tech Community item, this will give us visibility of the commonality of it and will help with our prioritization.https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform